# QMessageBox addButton() using standard icon/display

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make our popup messages boxes have more appropriate text, rather than the generic "Ok", "Cancel", etc. However, I don't see an easy way to get the standard icons on the buttons.

For example, normally the `QMessageBox::Save` button has an icon with it. Instead I want the text to be "Save Part", but since this is still essentially a save operation it'd be nice to have the same icon.

I'd be happy to have this tied to the Role, as all my custom test buttons map to one of the standard roles. Is there any easy way to get the standard icons onto the custom buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a button with [QMessageBox::addButton](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#addButton-2) to QMessageBox, then call the Button's  [setIcon](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#icon-prop) with the icon returned by the [QStyle::standardIcon](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qstyle.html#standardIcon)  you want.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to change the text on the `StandardButton` but keep the standard icon you can do the following:

```
QMessageBox *box = new QMessageBox("title", "text", QMessageBox::NoIcon, QMessageBox::Save, QMessageBox::Close, QMessageBox::Open);
box->button(QMessageBox::Save)->setText("Save part");
box->show();
```

This will result in following:
[image]

And the button will keep the same role